# JQuery loop through DIV's to hide /show

Tags: jquery

I have a combo box with choice 0 - 8 and 8 sets of input fields where each set of input fields are wrapped around a div with the same class.

I need to find out how to use Jquery to hide/unhide the divs based on the selected combobox value.
For example, if I select 2, then class="member1" and class="member2" needs to be visible, the rest are invisible. If i change my mind , and select 1, then class="member1" stay visible but member2 and the rest are set to invisible?

```
<div class="member1"> 
<input id="name1">
<input id="age1">
</div>
<div class="member2"> 
<input id="name2">
<input id="age2">
</div>
:
:
<div class="member8"> 
<input id="name8">
<input id="age8">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is rather simple. Considering `selected_number` is already an integer extracted from the select field you were talking about, the code could look like this:

```
jQuery(function(){
    var selected_number = 2;
    jQuery('.member1, .member2, .member3, .member4, .member5, .member6, .member7, .member8').hide();
    for (var i=1; i<=selected_number;i++){
        jQuery('.member'+i).show();
    }
});
```

As a proof [see this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5a6rh/) (change `selected_number` value to see how it works).

Comment: Awesome! Exactly what i was looking for... too simple once you've laid it out for me and lovin it

Answer (score 0):

Assume that `selectedValue` is an integer containing
the selected value.

```
for(var i=1;i<=8;i++){
   if(i<=selectedValue){
     $(".member"+i).show();
   } else {
     $(".member"+i).hide();     
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks bud... i didnt know how to evaluate the concatenation of the member to the integer i... i thought i had to use eval... but like tadeck above... yours is a great!

Answer (score 0):

You can add a generic class to every toggle-able element and hide them all when an option is selected, and then just show the desired one.

```
$('.toggle-able').hide();
$('.member' + selectedValue).show();
```